# Unable to Export contents of Data table (with French formatted Numbers ) to XML

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, internationalization

I have a data Table with numbers formatted according to the current regional settings. ie ( in French decimal separators are ',' instead of '.' in English). I need to export it to XML. Numbers in  XML needs to be formatted according to the current regional settings.But now numbers in XML are formatted in English.Is there any way to make the number formatting in XML according to current regional settings ( or based on the locale of the Data Table) during the exporting process  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. export them as strings not as numbers then do the conversion manually on the other side. The xsd number specification does not support localization (mainly because xml is supposed to be an universal data format easily parsed by anyone).

Comment: You could upvote the answer or better yet flag it as the accepted one